# MongoDb c# driver 2.0 Any in many to many

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-csharp-2.0

I have the following issue - how to check is there are any element from `int` array `mailListIds` contains in `MailLists` in `MailListId` field. I think it could be something like the following :

```
Builders<Profile>.Filter.AnyIn(p => p.MailLists.Select(m => m.MailListId), mailListIds)
```

But that code cannot be serialized into query. How to implement it ?

Comment: Builders<Profile>.Filter.In(p => p.MailLists[-1].MailListId, mailListIds) - It generates something like "p2l.$.listId" : { "$in" : [43156] } but i need the same without '$'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the problem by the following way :

```
 Builders<Profile>.Filter.Where(p => p.MailLists.Any(b => mailListIds.Contains(b.MailListId)))
```